# ¿Como subir multiples imagenes con Django Rest Framework?

Tags: javascript, python, base-de-datos, django

es posible subir multiples imagenes a un API creada con Django Rest Framework, he intentado hacerlo con un modelo con foreignKey solo para imagenes, pero habra alguna otra manera de que en un solo request el cliente envie tanto la info, como las imagenes a laz a la APIView de Django?

Answer (score 0):

Creando un FormData y alli agregar todos los elementos del POST.

```js
var formdata = new FormData()
formdata.append('valor1', "aqui va un valor")
formdata.append('valor1', "aqui va un valor")

this.$input_archivo.each(function() {
  if (this.type === 'file') {
    if (this.value !== '') {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.$input_archivo.prop("files").length; i++) {

        formdata.append('referencia_archivo', this.$input_archivo.prop("files")[i])
      }
    }
  }
})

$.ajax({
             url: url,
             method: "POST",
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             dataType: 'json',
             data: _data,
             success: function (_response) {
             },
             error: function (_response) {
             }
        })
```